# Take number value and return a string that represents an actual real condition

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

This seems like it should be easy, but I can't figure out how to do something so simple.

In one of my React pages, I have a pop-up that shows the current threat level for the character in a game.

The page gets a value of 0, 1, or 2.

I'd like to show the actual wording instead of just a number.

So I made an enum which seems like it should work, but I can't figure out how to get the string representation of the number.

Here is my code:

```
import React from 'react';

const threatStatus = {
    0: 'Clear',
    1: 'Stealth',
    2: 'Detected'
}

const CombatDetials = ({ detectionVal }) => (

    ReactDOM.createPortal(
        <div>
            <div>Current Threat Detection Level: threatStatus.{detectionVal} </div>
        </div>
    )
)

export default ProjectDetails;
```

But when I do that...I just see this:

```
threatStatus.0 or whatever the number is.
```

How can I get it to show the string, like 'clear', 'Stealth', or 'Detected' instead?

Thanks!

Comment: `threatStatus[detectionVal]` will give you what you're looking for. Also, wrap the whole thing in braces. `{threatStatus[detectionVal]}`

Answer (score 2):

To access the object properties you need these brackets, like that threatStatus[detectionVal] and to get the string of the variable you have to wrap it with the curly brackets - {}.

```
<div>
     <div>Current Threat Detection Level: {threatStatus[detectionVal]}</div>
</div>
```